# Nested tables using divs layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an HTML structure similar to this:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <ul>
         <li>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <ul>
         <li>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <ul>
         <li>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

And I'm using the following CSS to format it as a table:

```
ul {
    display: table;
    width:100%;
}
li {
    display: table-row;
}
li div {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

However, I need the all rows (parent and child) to all align to the left hand side, one below the other, without a 'nested' or 'indented' layout. Is this possible with the current HTML? (Note, I'm unable to change the HTML structure) The reason for using a 'table' layout is so that all columns are spaced nicely. I may be able to use Flex, but some columns have a lot more text than others, so the table format seems to work best.

Any help is appreciated!

https://jsfiddle.net/randkb/os7eq493/3/

The outcome I'd like is this:

[image]

instead of this:

[image]

Comment: Could you make your code into a runnable snippet - with a bit of data in each cell - so we can see more clearly what is going on. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sure thing, here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/randkb/os7eq493/3/

Comment: Please share the screenshot of the outcome which you want

Comment: Thanks Kairav, I've done this now. :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the expected result. Will check it.

Comment: I have shared you the link, please check below my Answer comment

Answer (score 1):

```
Click on below link, it have your defined outcome.
```

[Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/kairavthakar2016/c5a1hfrv/32/)

Comment: Please let me know if you still have any issues.

Comment: Thanks Kairav, the only issue here is that I loose the properties of a table where columns are equalised in width. Even using flex: 1 isn't an option, since some cells have much more content than others, and therefore becomes unbalanced.

Comment: Please check this result: https://jsfiddle.net/kairavthakar2016/c5a1hfrv/32/

Comment: You can try by adding more content and check the unbalance thing

Comment: I've done that here: https://jsfiddle.net/randkb/ct0Lwd36/2/

Comment: This is the table in reality: https://rwasp.hubsmart.co.uk/Screenshot%202022-11-15%20at%2011.21.19.png

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information. So now I think only concern is of the width.
We can either fixed the width.

Comment: I've made the width 100%, rather than fixed. I've also added flex-direction: column; to ul > li > ul and this has helped things. I think once I've tidied up the output (as there are some rows with empty columns), it'll look much neater! Thanks for all your help!!